# Arrays: Combining them in such a way

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to combine two arrays but I think all that I've read here is different than what I want to achieve. So here are my initial arrays:

```
oldArray = ['name','age','address','number'];

firstArray = ['Peter Parker','16','Queens','123456789']; // this is dynamic but will still have the same set nonetheless.
```

so what I want to do is combine them into this:

```
heroList  = ['name','age','address','number'],['Peter Parker','16','Queens','123456789'];
```

So I've tried combining them using `concat() method` and it was producing the wrong output so Im wondering how I should format them to combine to my desired output.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not possible because a variable can't be "two arrays" like that ... did you mean `heroList  = [['name','age','address','number'],['Peter  Parker','16','Queens','123456789']];` - which is simply `heroList = [oldArray, firstArray]`

Comment: @JaromandaX this is exactly what I wanted to do thanks! I'll accept your answer since you're the first one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments your notation for `heroList` is syntactically wrong, but I am guessing you mean: `heroList  = [['name','age','address','number'],['Peter Parker','16','Queens','123456789']];` ?

Maybe something like this:

```
oldArray = ['name','age','address','number'];
firstArray = ['Peter Parker','16','Queens','123456789'];

var heroList = [
  oldArray,
  firstArray
];
```

Answer (score 1):

By reading you expected output, the `heroList` should be an object, with the two arrays as attribute. Try this:

```
var oldArray = ['name','age','address','number'];

var firstArray = ['Peter Parker','16','Queens','123456789'];

var heroList = [];

heroList.push(oldArray);
heroList.push(firstArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a multi dimensional array:

```
heroList = [[ 'name' , 'age' , 'address' , 'number' ],[ 'Peter Parker' , '16' , 'Queens' , '123456789' ]];
```

You can make this from a single dimensional array like:

```
arr1 = [ 'name' , 'age' , 'address' , 'number' ]
arr2=[ 'Peter Parker' , '16' , 'Queens' , '123456789' ]; 
newArr=[arr1,arr2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
var heroList = (firstArray.join(",") + "," + oldArray.join(",")).split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right the example is syntactically wrong so In a hierarchy order i will just accept the first persons answer.Thanks